# What actually is "conflicting type"?

Tags: c, math

```
#include<stdio.h>
long fact(int x);

int main()
{   long x=fact(5);
    printf("%ld",x);
}

long fact(long x)
{
    long prod=1;
    int i=1;
    if(x==0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        while(i<=x)
        {
        prod=prod*i;
        i++;
        }
    return prod;
    }

}
```

Here's the code I am using to find out the value of e (to the power x,here x=1)
[image: e^x series]

Now I get the following ERROR:

> error: conflicting types for 'fact'
> I am using long return type all the time

EDIT:
I changed the definition signature and it worked:

```
#include<stdio.h>

long fact(int x)
{
    long prod=1;
    int i=1;
    if(x==0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        while(i<=x)
        {
        prod=prod*i;
        i++;
        }
    return prod;
    }

}

int main()
{   long x=fact(7);
    printf("%ld",x);
}
```

Comment: You need to put a semicolon on line two, and your signatures for fact mismatch, your forward declaration takes an int, while your actual function takes a long.

Comment: @Dmitry would you please mark the problem of mismatch? I can see both the fact functions have same return type long(in prototype and declaration)

Comment: Change your `long fact(int x);` to `long fact(long x);`.

Comment: long fact(`int` x); `int` should be `long`

Comment: @Dmitry okay brother but why long return type functions can't take int as parameter?

Comment: @IbtidaBinAhmed They can, you can also change the definition signature to `long fact(int x)` below your main.

Comment: @fukanchik okay but reason?Can I not input int for factorial(as it is a small number) and get factorial a large number so return type long?

Comment: @IbtidaBinAhmed You can. Your issue is with the signature mismatch between your forward declaration(at the top of the file) and your function definition(below your main), you have a mismatch[`long fact(int x);`, `long fact(long x)`]. You have to change one of  them.

Comment: Notes on ranges with factorials: • A 32-bit integer can store factorials up to 12!
• A 64-bit integer can store factorials up to 20!
• A 128-bit (unsigned) integer can store factorials up to 34!
• A 256-bit integer can store factorials up to 57!
• A 512-bit (unsigned) integer can store factorials up to 98!
• Using IEEE 754 64-bit floating-point arithmetic, you can store
approximations up to 170!  (7.257415615307994E+306).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration `long fact(int x);` and definition `long fact(long x) ...` don't agree on type of the argument `x`.  Here is a more streamlined version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long fact(int x) {
    long prod = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= x; i++)
        prod *= i;
    return prod;
}

int main() {
    long x = fact(7);
    printf("%ld", x);
}
```

As factorial grows so fast I suggest adding an assert or error check that x <= 21 if `long` is `8` bytes (22! > 2^64-1).  Factorial is usually defined for non-negative numbers so consider using unsigned types: `unsigned long` for the return type, and maybe even `unsigned char x` for the argument.